# How to restrict text search to a certain subset of the database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, full-text-search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a large central database of around 1 million heavy records. In my app, for every user I would have a subset of rows from central table, which would be very small (probably 100 records each).When a particular user has logged in , I would want to search on this data set only. Example:

Say I have a central database of all cars in the world. I have a user profile for General Motors(GM) , Ferrari etc. When GM is logged in I just want to search(a full text search and not fire a sql query) for those cars which are manufactured by GM. Also GM may launch/withdraw a model in which case central db would be updated & so would be rowset associated with GM. In case of acquisitions, db of certain profiles may change without launch/removal of new car. So central db wont change then , but rowsets may.

Whats the best way to implement such a design ? These smaller row sets would need to be dynamic depending on user activities.

We are on Rails 2.3.5 and use thinking_sphinx as the connector and Sphinx/MySQL for search and relational associations.

Answer (score 0):

how about using has_many :through

```
class Manufacturer
class Car
class ManufacturerCarRelation

Manufacturer
 has_many :manufacturer_car_relations
 has_many :cars through => manufacturer_car_relations

ManufacturerCarRelation
 belongs_to :manufacturer
 belongs_to :car
```

Comment: You are looking at problem in relational domain only. 

To make myself clearer: 
I want to apply a full text search on sub zone of central db index. I don't want to clone data to each user's table & index it separately , in  addition to indexing main db.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to define your index with something like this:

```
class Car
  define_index do
    indexes description
    has 'cars.manufacturer_id', :as => :manufacturer_id, :type => :integer
  end
end
```

and then use [field conditions](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/searching.html#conditions), like:

```
Car.search "red", :conditions => {:manufacturer_id => gm.id}
```

or [attribute filters](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/searching.html#filters):

```
Car.search "red", :with => {:manufacturer_id => gm.id}
```

Comment: 1) AAh...slightly bad example chosen.My bad.  Model would need many to many relation. So every car should actually contain multiple manufacturers.So this solution wont work.

2) I am not sure we have restricted search even here. We are still be using the whole table & restriction is just passed as an sql condition. Can we somehow just restrict the search domain itself ?